# Javascript/jquery countdown freeze at 00:00

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I programmed this js/jquery countdown. How can I make when time difference is 0 that my timer freezes at 00:00 and stay like that for 1:30min and changes to red font?
Example: Remainig time 00:05, after 5s it's 00:00(red font) and it stays like that for 1:30 minute.

```
var timer1;
function cdtd1() {
    var sad1 = new Date();
    var dolazak1 = new Date(sad1.getFullYear(),sad1.getMonth(),sad1.getDate(),13,01,00);
    var timeDiff1 = dolazak1.getTime() - sad1.getTime();
    if (timeDiff1 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer1);
        $("#Box1").remove();
    }
    if (timeDiff1 > 1500000) {
        clearInterval(timer1);
        $("#Box1").remove();
    }


    var sekunde1 = Math.floor(timeDiff1 / 1000);
    var minute1 = Math.floor(sekunde1 / 60);
    var sati1 = Math.floor(minute1 / 60);
    var dani1 = Math.floor(sati1 / 24);
    sati1 %= 24;
    minute1 %= 60;
    sekunde1 %= 60;

    $("#dani1Box").html(dani1);
    $("#sati1Box").html(sati1 + ':');
    $("#minute1Box").html('7-Dubrava '+ minute1 + ':');
    $("#sekunde1Box").html(sekunde1);

    timer1 = setTimeout(cdtd1, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd1();
});
```

This is html:

```
<div id="Box1">

<h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>

<div id="minute1Box"></div>

<div id="sekunde1Box"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to clear your timer at all, because you are using `setTimeout`, which is a fire-once timer.

You need to **not** call `setTimeout` when the countdown is either done, or the time difference hits your threshold of 1,500 seconds. I would do like this:

```
if (timeDiff1 <= 0) {
    $("#Box1").remove();
    return;
}
if (timeDiff1 > 1500000) {
    $("#Box1").remove();
    return;
}
```

Second, to answer your original question, when the time has hit zero, simply set the css class of your `Box1` to some CSS class that has a red font, and also set the text of your `div` elements to zeros. Then set a new timeout for a function that removes your `Box1` after 90 seconds.

And by the way, consider using `text()` instead of `html()` when you are setting the text contents of an element and not the html contents.

```
if (timeDiff1 <= 0) {
    $("#Box1").addClass("timer-warning");

    $("#dani1Box").text("0");
    $("#sati1Box").text("0:");
    $("#minute1Box").text('7-Dubrava 0:');
    $("#sekunde1Box").text("0");

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#Box1").remove();
    }, 90000);
    return;
}
```

In your CSS file:

```
.timer-warning {
    color: #f00;
}
```